# Integrating Eclipse JDT Core into a new editor

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense, eclipse-jdt

I'm building a Java IDE and am trying to implement autocompletion or intellisense. After looking around for something that will do most of the work for me (not reinventing the wheel etc) I've pulled the code for Eclipse JDT core and am trying to figure out how to implement it in my own IDE. I'm obviously working under the assumption that this is possible.

If anyone knows a lot about Eclipse JDT Core, implementing intellisense, or other fun things that would help me accomplish my goal and would like to weigh in, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: XText might not help you *directly* but can offer some clues about the implementation of autocompletion in an Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Another module that could help when implementing intellisense would be **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**
(might be a bit *too* generic for your specific JDT domain)

> Xtext is a framework for development of programming languages and domain specific languages (DSLs). Just describe your very own DSL using Xtext's simple `EBNF` grammar language and the generator will create a parser, an AST-meta model (implemented in EMF) as well as a full-featured Eclipse text editor from that.

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/0_7_2/images/getting-started-editor.png](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/0_7_2/images/getting-started-editor.png)

Comment: This is a cool project but kind of the reverse of what I need, thanks though!